# Hiding System icons in Notification area?

Tags: notifications, system

Does anybody know a reliable way to remove system icons from the notification area? I have a smaller screen on my (rooted, default ROM) Optimus T and I find some of the system notifications icons unnecessary. I would prefer to find an app to do it rather than have to do it myself, I'm always nervous about changing framework pieces by hand in a text editor.

For instance, I work full time and use my phone as my alarm clock. I will, for the entire life of my device, have an alarm set. I do not need an icon telling me I have an alarm.

Also, I have no need to know if headphones are plugged into my device. If they're plugged into my device, they're plugged into my ears, and that's an easier indicator while not taking up screen space.

Lastly, I keep my phone on vibrate. I never want my phone to ring because if I'm talking to somebody and my phone goes off, if I answer, I'm rude to who I'm face to face talking to. If I don't answer, then the person I'm talking to knows that I blatantly ignored a call; I'm worried if they call me, they'll think I didn't answer because I did the same thing. On vibrate, I'm the only one who knows what calls I answer/ignore.

Does anybody know an app to let me turn off these system icons in the notification area?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=780614) is an excellent thread on XDA on how to do this the *really* hard way (manually, with [de-compiling](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=8124681&postcount=11) and [recompiling](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=8607362&postcount=47) the framework.) I would highly recommend *not* flashing the different mods from that thread because they are based on files from a different device. Also, backing up the files you will be playing with is a must.

I have not found any 3rd-party apps that can do this. Could be because this mod requires edits to system files that are very device-specific.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, I've stumbled across this as well but I'm very reluctant about changing up these files myself. I was hoping there was an app that could properly/reliably make these changes for me. But that seems to be less and less of a possibility...

Comment: You can always chime in on that thread and ask (beg, bribe) for a kind soul to help you edit and re-compile your specific services.jar file.  :)

Comment: I'd rather do it myself than let them do it. I'm a software developer. I've worked in large systems which is why I have a healthy fear/respect for modifying them. On the other hand, with the system being as complicated as it is, I don't trust my phone to somebody else to do it. I'll think it over and may do it myself...